# Thermogenic transfer of cryogenic gases

Tags: thermodynamics, cryogenics

Is there any chemicals or substances that can be gases or liquids at around 5 kelvins, and that can also have a high thermal conductivity, at least 3 w/mk

Comment: Helium is the only thing I can think of that is liquid at 5K. It does have a high thermal conductivity though I don't know the exact figure.

Comment: It's 0.15 k/wm but i was looking for a specific chemical not element

Comment: I suspect no such chemical exists ...